# Saving and loading mxGraph file without using a server

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I want to create an editor which can save and load (XML format) without using a server. I see the example of grapheditor but it seems that code need a server in order to save.

How do I save/load in mxGraph without the use of a server, that is downloading and uploading the file through browser. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot save to the filesystem without the user seeing a save dialog, it's just not possible. GraphEditor is delivered from a server, but doesn't need a server in order to save locally, as long as you have a modern browser capable of doing that (read as Chrome, Firefox, Edge).

Answer (score 0):

In the past Javascript was only allowed to load ressources if the user selected them via the file dialogs. Writing a file was and is still considered a security risk.

But modern browsers support the local storage! You can enable the use of the local storage in the GraphEditor example (https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html) by adding the GET parameter storage=local to your request.

For example: localhost:8000/index.html?storage=local

This is the explanation from the GraphEditor code:

```
// - storage=local: Enables HTML5 local storage.
```

Comment: I have downloaded this source code from Git. Locally not working save functionality it is showing menus link like "Undefined" error. Do you have any idea about this?